# @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") redirected server too many times

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, authorization

I'm trying to learn the **@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity** annotation in Spring. Here is an example that doesnt seem to work for me.

**THIS WORKS:** Let's say I have a global controller that shows the logged-in username on every page, like so:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalController {

    @ModelAttribute("username")
    public String getCurrUser(Principal principal) {
        if (principal != null) {
            return principal.getName();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**THIS DOESNT WORK:** The same controller now, but this time with **preAuthorize** annotation. This returns me the following error message: *localhost redirected you too many times.*

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalController {

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @ModelAttribute("username")
    public String getCurrUser(Principal principal) {

        return principal.getName();
    }
}
```

---

My **SecurityConfig class** is annotated like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...
```

So how can I solve this error message with **PreAuthorize** annotation?

Comment: reverse '@Preauthorize and @modelattribute....  @ModelAttribute("username")  @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public String getCurrUser(Principal principal) {

Comment: Tried it, but it still returns the same error message :(

Comment: boolean check =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated(); try this in 1st method and tell me the result??

Comment: returns true when im logged in and when im not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have been learning Spring and Spring security too. 
Doe your base url pattern has restriction or not ? 
I tried to redirect all the logins to the same a point which according to my configuration required authentication.

See if the configuration is correct and access security is properly set on the code.